# I think I am getting different AIC & BIC values in a regression model built using statsmodel package in Python

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, statsmodels

I built a single factor (univariate regression) model and when I do

```
aic = results.aic
```

and when do

```
aic = results.nobs*np.log(results.ssr/results.nobs) + 4
```

I get different outputs. Which one is correct?

The second formula gives the same results as SAS Base 9.4 outputs

```
  aic = results.aic #from statsmodel packages
  aic = results.nobs*np.log(results.ssr/results.nobs) + 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculation between AIC in statsmodels and  SAS differ when it comes to model dimension interpretation.

In statmodels, aic looks like:

[Statsmodels Eval_metrics source code](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/c30c29a2c2d2ac11c730d21c19a0556839535ff3/statsmodels/tools/eval_measures.py#L309)

```
def aic(llf, nobs, df_modelwc):

    return -2. * llf + 2. * df_modelwc
```

where df_modelwc is

```
df_modelwc : int
        number of parameters including constant
```

while in SAS interpretation:

[SAS Mixed Procedure Documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mixed_sect008.htm#statug.mixed.mixedic)

AIC looks like

-2LL + 2d, 
where 'd is an effective number of estimated covariance parameters'.

Both of the interpretations are correct, but you cannot compare goodness of fit measure based on interpretation from two different sources.

Comment: How about Shapiro Wilk test (for testing normality of residuals)? Is that also different?

Comment: Now if only I knew how to calculate an effective number of estimated covariance parameters in python...

Comment: @DanCiborowski-MSFT based on your answer, I rethink my answer to that question. and at the moment I am not sure why this definition should differ. 'effective number  of estimated covariance parameters' appears in MIXED procedure in restricted maximum likelihood case. while on traditional log likelihood function, the parameter d is defined as the parameters of the model. I'll come back to this question today, later.

Comment: I have come to realize that the differences between SAS ARIMA and Python ARIMA are so different that the AIC value doesn't really matter. I am exploring simply trying to get my feature importance to come out slightly similar. Right now arima combinations that are significant in SAS, do not appear significant in Python >.<